# How can I get titanium to allow setting a default parameter value for a JavaScript function

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Basically, the following pattern is rejected and seen as an error.

```
function fooBar(flag = true) {
  // flag will be set to true is someone called fooBar() without any parameters
}
```

**EDIT**: I have added the following snippet to show the real action. This is more elegant, easier to read and maintain and faster to run (no underscore requirement)... and it is supported by JavaScript.

```js
function greet(param = "World") {
 alert("Hello " + param + "!");
}

greet(); // Will alert "Hello World"
greet("Thomas"); // Will alert "Hello Thomas"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a javascript question than a Titanium one.
You can use the `isUndefined` function from underscore lib (include with Alloy) :

```
function fooBar(flag) {
  // flag will be set to true is someone called fooBar() without any parameters
  if(_.isUndefined(flag))
    flag = true;

}
```

Don't forget that Titanium Mobile use ECMAScript 5 and default value argument for function was introduced with ECMAScript 6 : http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-default-argument.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I disagree. JavaScript does support the default values for functions parameters. I have edited the question to add a runnable code snippet to show you what I really meant.

Comment: Ok, good to know. So, what is the error ? Can you post the console log ?

Comment: The initial error is: Unexpected token "=". And depending on where I use this pattern, it result into a cascade of bunch of errors that don't make any sense. And if I try to compile, I get a pop-up says: Errors exist in required project(s) ... Proceed with launch? ... with a checkbox suggesting to always launch without asking.

Comment: I thought that I could modify some of the settings in Titanium Studio, but after hours of searching I gave up. I thought that it would have had similar flexibilities that IntelliJ based IDEs have when in comes to syntax validation.

Comment: Don't forget that Titanium Mobile use ECMAScript 5 and default value argument for function was introduced with ECMAScript 6 : http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-default-argument.html.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it.

Comment: If you want ES6 support, you can follow this tutorial : http://www.tidev.io/2015/10/28/titanium-alloy-and-es6/